# How to access the dataTables in a DataSet

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created this DataSet and add a DataTable on it.

[image]

My problem is I don't know how to access this DataTable *(Addresses)* in my program.

[image]

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: it seems like you're working with the *type* of your `dataset` and `datatable`, but I believe you should be working with an *instance* if you want to use it as a data source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DataSet1 is the **type**; you need an *instance* that you load with data via an adapter. That should then be easily available:

```
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
// todo: use an adapter to load the desired data
var addresses = ds.Addresses;
```

Or

```
var addresses = ds["Addresses"];
```

That said; dataset/DataTable is **definitely not** how I would do data access. You might want to look instead at tools like LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework.